# Julia package for managing distributed SpGEMM

Tags: multiprocessing, julia, sparse-matrix, distributed-computing

Does anyone know a performant package under Juia to compute sparse matrix-matrix multuplication (SpGEMM) on a distributed cluster (MPI)?
I'm not sure if Elemental.jl is able to manage such computations.
I'm looking for something simple (such as COSMA.jl for dense systems), all help would be welcome...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Elemental does appear to be able to handle this. In particular, using Elemental.jl you should be able to create a sparse distributed array with `Elemental.DistSparseMatrix`, which you should AFAICT be able to multiply with `mul!` or similar.

This does not not appear to be extensively documented, and in particular filling this `DistSparseMatrix` with the desired values does not appear to be trivial, but some examples appear in https://github.com/JuliaParallel/Elemental.jl/blob/master/test/lav.jl, among a [few other places in the package source](https://github.com/JuliaParallel/Elemental.jl/search?q=DistSparseMatrix)

Beyond this, while there are of course packages such as DistributedArrays.jl and the SparseArrays stdlib, there is not to my knowledge any sparse, distributed array package in pure Julia yet, so a wrapper package like Elemental.jl is going to be your best bet.

Other packages that should be generically capable of sparse distributed matrix multiplication appear to include PETSc and Trilinos, both of which do have Julia wrappers (the latter of which appears unmaintained, though [see also](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6tNZXaFi_E) the presentation thereon). With [PETSc.jl](https://github.com/JuliaParallel/PETSc.jl), it appears that you should be able to make a "MATSEQ" sparse matrix by passing a Julia `SparseMatrixCSC` to `PETSc.Mat`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It appears that only SpGEMV is possible with Elemental, not SpGEMM. I'll try with PETSc and Trilinos.